# Converting Double to Date?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I want to convert a double value into a date

```
        String firstdate =startdate.Text;
        String lastdate = enddate.Text;

        DateTime enteredDate1 = DateTime.Parse(firstdate);
        DateTime enteredDate2 = DateTime.Parse(lastdate);

        double stdate= enteredDate1.ToOADate();
        double endate = enteredDate2.ToOADate();


        sliderStartLabel.Text = "Year" + firstdate + "to";

        slider_TextBox_SliderExtender.Minimum = stdate;
        sliderEndLabel.Text = lastdate;
        slider_TextBox_SliderExtender.Maximum=endate;

        DateTime myDate = DateTime.FromOADate(stdate);

        String date = myDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

        slider_TextBox.Text = date;
```

I expect the output as yyyy/mm/dd format but I got the output as a double value(ex:- 3456)

Comment: Assuming by "output" you mean the value displayed in `slider_TextBox.Text`, then I don't see how it's possible to get a numeric value.

Comment: Why do you expect `yyyy/mm/dd` format if the second to last line formats the date with `dd/MM/yyyy`?

Comment: If you put a breakpoint on stdate, and myDate, are the values and types what you'd expect?

Comment: yes Jhon i need to show the converted date value inside that textbox

Comment: gunr2171 the format doesn't matter all i need is to show a date value on the slider_TextBox.Text

Comment: Techgration I'm not clear with your question

Comment: Unless the `SliderExtender` is _changing_ the date, this is effective the same as `DateTime.FromOADate(stdate.ToOADate())` - @Techgration is correctly suggesting adding a breakpoint and checking the value of `stdate` to see if it has changed.

Comment: all i want is to convert the double value stdate to date and display it inside the slider_TextBox.Text

Comment: Note that `FromOADate` will either return a datetime or throw, it cannot return a double, as @John pointed out. Can you provide a code sample that reproduces your problem?

Comment: The code you have posted _should_ do just that `DateTime.FromOADate(DateTime.Today.ToOADate()).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")` returns "11/10/2019"

Comment: It worked thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you are work with Unix timestamp like calendar contract in Xamarin.android then this code will work fine.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double d = 3456;
        long l= Convert.ToInt64(d);
        DateTime dt = new DateTime().AddMilliseconds(l);
        Console.WriteLine(dt);

        DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,0).AddMilliseconds(l);
        Console.WriteLine(epoch);

        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        Console.WriteLine(now);
        Console.WriteLine("Datetime");



        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    protected long GetDateTimeMS(DateTime dt)
    {
        DateTime epoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).ToLocalTime();
        return (long)(dt - epoch).TotalMilliseconds;
    }
}
```